# Is there any operation manual about Ubuntu18.04 system?

Tags: 18.04

I am a beginner of Ubuntu, and I have been using CentOS system before. Is there any operation manual about Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this guide
[Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf)